# how to fix app service runs out of temp space?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

i have isolated i2 service plan the app service runs windows .net web apps .

the local\temp keeps filling up.(I have a process to delete files but it sometimes can't keep up)

should I just attach a azure disk drive "E"?

Or is there a way to increase temp size?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can attach a azure disk drive, but according to this [post](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files), the disk usage amount seems to be based on SKU. In other words, the higher the SKU level, the larger the disk size that can be used, and the size cannot be specified manually. If possible, you can try to scale to I3.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot increase the temp folder size inside a App Service. If you wish to increase temp space you can do it by scaling up the app service plan to higher tiers.

- The “Disk Space” depends on the App Service plan you're using. It's 1 GB for Free, 10 GB for Basic, 50 GB for Standard and 250 GB for Premium, refer the document for more details on these limits: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/.
- App Service also limits the amount of temporary local storage available to each app to prevent individual apps from consuming excessive amounts of local file storage.
- Here is the information where you can know about the files that are dealt on Azure WebApp (Persisted files, Temporary files and Machine level read-only files) and there [limits](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) as well

Refer the below blog which will help you in understanding the disk space availability

[Azure App Service - What is taking my disk space for my Azure Web App](https://puneet-gupta.github.io/puneetgupta/2017/06/06/azure-app-service-what-is-taking-my-disk-space-for-my-azure-web-app/)